# Thymleaf: I need the radio buttons to increment the th:field array list

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

```
<tr th:each="i : ${output.qaCombo}">
<td th:text="${i.questionPhrase}"></td>
<input type="radio" th:field="*{answersChosen}" value="A" /><td th:text="${i.Ans1}"></td>
<input type="radio" th:field="*{answersChosen}" value="B" /><td th:text="${i.Ans2}"></td>
<input type="radio" th:field="*{answersChosen}" value="C" /><td th:text="${i.Ans3}"></td>
<input type="radio" th:field="*{answersChosen}" value="D" /><td th:text="${i.Ans4}"></td>
<br/>
</tr>
```

Result of my code:

[image]

"answersChosen" is an ArrayList in my java code. The webpage only lets me select one radio button because the index of the array is not specified. I need each radio button to fill a spot in the array with the value. Like this: answerChosen[0] = "A", answerChosen[1] = "B"
I appreciate any help you guys can offer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With th:each in Thymeleaf you can declare an iteration status variable.

```
<tr th:each="i, iter : ${output.qaCombo}">
```

and then in the loop you can use iter.index or iter.size to do what you need:

```
th:field="*{answersChosen[__${iter.index}__]}"
```

See Tutorial: [Using Thymeleaf - 6.2 Keeping iteration status](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status).